# SQL Query MIN MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to write a query in SQL Server that joins two tables like this:

Lets say my first table is TB1:

```
Id     Date       ProductId
1111   1-Jan-08   345
1112   5-Apr-10   345
1113   1-Jan-13   345
1114   1-Oct-14   345
1115   1-Jan-15   345
```

Second Table is TB2:

```
Id2  Date       ProductId   CompanyId  Flag
1    1-Jan-14   345         12         1
2    2-Jan-14   345         13         1
3    4-Jan-14   345         14         1
4    12-Nov-14  345         15         1
```

The result should be:

```
Id    ProductId   CompanyId
1111  345         12
1112  345         12
1113  345         12
1114  345         14
1115  345         15
```

That is, when TB1.Date < all entries in TB2.Date -> Then the CompanyID corresponding to minimum date in TB2 should be picked.

When TB1.Date > all entries in Tb2.Date -> Then the CompanyId for maximum date in TB2 should be taken

When Tb1.Date is between the dates in TB2, then the CompanyId for the lower side of date should be picked.

Thanks!

Comment: You should show us what you have tried (sql), at this moment you just let us do your work.

Comment: It sounds like you realy only have 2 cases: 1) take the highest date entry from tb2 that is lower than the entry from tb1; 2) if no such entry exists, take the lowest entry from tb2.

Comment: Thanks! What sort of SQL statements would help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but haven't tested it extensively. you can try this and modify/optimize it wherever you feel necessary.

This code checks the following

- If the date of the current record in TB1 is less than min(all dates)
  for the corresponding product in TB2. If so min(date) is returned and
  the corresponding Company ID (1st condition)
- If the date of the current record in TB1 is more than max(all dates) for the corresponding product in TB2. If so max(date) is
  returned and the corresponding Company ID (2nd condition)
- If the date of the current record is in between the date range of second table for the corresponding product, it pulls the max date
  record that is less than the date in TB1 we are referring to.

Let us know if that helps

```
With daterange
as 
(Select ProductID, max(Date) as maxdate, min(Date) as mindate
from TB2
Group by ProductID)

Select distinct a.ProductId, a.Date as TB1Date, 
Case when a.Date < c.mindate then c.mindate 
     when a.Date > c.maxdate then c.maxdate 
     when a.Date between c.mindate and c.maxdate then (Select top 1 a1.Date     from TB2 a1 where a1.Date < a.Date and a1.ProductId = a.ProductId order by date desc) End as TB2Date,
 d.CompanyId as CompanyId 
FROM TB1 a 
Left join daterange c on a.ProductId = c.ProductId 
Left join TB2 d on (Case when a.Date < c.mindate then c.mindate 
     when a.Date > c.maxdate then c.maxdate 
     when a.Date between c.mindate and c.maxdate then (Select top 1 a1.Date     from TB2 a1 where a1.Date < a.Date and a1.ProductId = a.ProductId order by     date desc) End) = d.Date
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. For codes, select the code then use the "Code sample" button on the toolbar (or simply indent all code lines via 4 spaces). Also please explain how and why this answer could help not only for the current OP, but for further readers. Please read [answer] in [help] for more info.